# How to run Jenkins Job in linux server?

Tags: linux, jenkins

In Linux server I have installed Jenkins and created new Job & Using Shell Command to execute the job. The shell command which I am using is `bash run.bat`. Where run.bat file contains following code `java -cp ./lib/*:./bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`. Whenever I am trying to build this project from Jenkins it gives following error message in console

```
[EmailableReporter] [ERROR] Unable to create output file
java.io.FileNotFoundException: test-output/emailable-report.html (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
```

How to fix this error...?

Below shows the Log file....

```css
Building in workspace /home/probe7qa/probe7qa.svn/icoreemrtests/onc2014/170.314.a.9/src/eNotes
[eNotes] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1602450082114672082.sh
+ bash run.bat
[TestNG] Running:
  /home/probe7qa/probe7qa.svn/icoreemrtests/onc2014/170.314.a.9/src/eNotes/testng.xml


===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Skips: 12
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: set the test-output dir permission so that jenkins user is able to write in it.

Comment: Already permission is set to 755..

Comment: under which user? jenkins runs under its own user.

Comment: I have created one admin user using jenkins(Matrix based security) and running the job...

Comment: this has nothing todo with users you create in jenkins. just chown the test-output directory to the jenkins user... for testing purposes you can also chmod 777 and try it. (but dont leave it that way) ... its just a simple permission problem and has nothing todo with jenkins itself.

Comment: After Changing Permission to 777 following error displayed ===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Skips: 12
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: That doesn't tell us anything about what went wrong. Is there no more detailed output for the tests, no log?

Comment: the "failure" is in your script. jenkins does nothing wrong. you have to debug your script. can you enhance the verbosity of the script?

Comment: Same script runs perfectly in my localhost(windows os). I have uploaded same file to Jenkins which is installed in Linux server... Jenkins installed in Linux facing this problem